# Intersection multiplicity formula in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In $\mathbb{P}^2$ we can calculate the intersection multiplicity of two curves given by polynomials $f$, $g$ in $P = (P_x,P_y,1)$ by calculating $\dim_k (k[[x,y]]/(f(x+P_x,y+P_y,1),g(x+P_x,y+P_y,1)))$ and I was wondering if such a formula also exists in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

For example if we take the twisted cubic $I = (xz-y^2,yt-z^2,xt-yz)$ and the line $J = (x,y)$ then we would have intersection multiplicity 2 at $[0:0:0:1]$ because the line is tangent to the curve there, and multiplicity 0 everywhere else.

Comment: If two subvarieties $Y,Z$ of $X$ meet at one point, then one can define a number, the length of $\mathcal{O}_X,x/I(Y)+I(Z)$, as you have done above. But, this lacks most of the global properties like Bezout's theorem.